# Optional binding a color in swiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a question about optional bindings in swiftUI. I have a struct:

```
struct LightPairing: View {
    @Binding var light: Color?
    init(light: Binding<Color?>) {
        self._light = light
    }
    // the rest of the code, such as body is omitted since it is very long
}
```

I want to give the light property a default value of nil, light: Binding<Color?> = nil, but it does not work. Is there anyway to get around this issue?

Edit: When I do:

`light: Binding<Color?> = nil` I get the error message saying

> "Nil default argument value cannot be converted to type
> Binding<Color?>"

Comment: What doesn't work? Is there an error?

Comment: your variable worked normally as I tested. I believed you are having a different error because you did not include the var body: some View {}

Comment: Your provided ui is missing a lot of code. let us see your full code.

Answer (score 2):

Your property is of type `Binding<Color?>` so you can't simply assign `nil`.  You have to assign `Binding<Color?>` where the bound value is `nil`.

You can do this via `Binding.constant()`:

```
struct LightPairing: View {
    @Binding var light: Color?
    init(light: Binding<Color?> = .constant(nil)) {
        self._light = light
    }
    // the rest of the code, such as body is omitted since it is very long
}
```

Now, if you don't provide a binding for `light` a default value will be supplied for you.

Answer (score 0):

A `@Binding` takes a value from another property, such as a `@State` property wrapper (a property that owns the value).

You can either set the `@Binding` from a property in another struct (elsewhere)…

```
@State private var lightElsewhere: Color? = nil
```

then call…

```
LightPairing(light: $lightElsewhere)
```

or alternatively change your `@Binding` to a State property in this struct.

```
@State private var light: Color? = nil
```

Where this occurs will depend on your app logic.

Answer (score 0):

Try like below:-

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        LightPairing(light: .constant(nil))
    }
}
struct LightPairing: View {
    @Binding var light: Color?
    init(light: Binding<Color?>) {
        self._light = light
    }
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            //Some Code
        }
    }
    // the rest of the code, such as body is omitted since it is very long
}
```